# Acessando variáveis dinamicamente em linguagem C

Tags: c, variáveis, hash, dicionário

Entendo que é possível acessar variáveis dinamicamente em JavasScript, mas fazer isto em C, não acho em nenhum lugar.

Segue o código em Javascript:

```javascript
var n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
n1 = n2 = n3 = n4 = n5 = 0; // define que todas essas variáveis são '0'

for (var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    console.log( window["n"+i] ); // acessa a variável de nome 'n' + número do índice
}

// definimos novos valores para as mesmas variáveis
n1 = "Maçã";
n2 = "Pêra";
n3 = "Uva";
n4 = "Abóbora";
n5 = "Chuchu";

for (var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    console.log( window["n"+i] ); // faz o mesmo que antes, mas agora as variáveis têm seus valores definidos
}
```

A minha questão é: "Como fazer a mesma coisa na linguagem C?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela linguagem puramente não dá. Você tem duas opções:

1. Fazer direito o que precisa ser feito nesse caso, então ao invés de criar variáveis cujo índice fazem parte do nome dela, crie uma variável onde o índice é destacado, ou seja, crie um *array* comum. Esse problema é facilmente resolvido assim:

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        int n[5] = { 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d\n", n[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) n[i] = i + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }
   ```

   Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cdZtj2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vzwchymj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Access.c).

   Lembrando que em C não dá para as variáveis terem vários tipos de forma tradicional. Como sempre há truques possíveis para simular isso, mas não vem ao caso para esta questão.
2. Se for outro problema mais complexo onde realmente exista a necessidade de usar um índice como um nome qualquer, que seja uma *string* que pode ser manipulada, então a solução é fazer o que o JavaScript fez e deu pronto para o seu usuário, que é criar uma [tabela de *hash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

   C é uma linguagem que entrega o básico, o resto é com o programador providenciar. Então ou você escreve uma ou arruma uma biblioteca pronta que faça isto.

   A sintaxe nunca será das melhores. C não é conhecida por providenciar muitas formas de açúcar sintático. Embora o pré-processador pode ajudar um pouco se souber o que está fazendo e tiver criatividade. Se não souber, pode causar mais problema que solução.

   Uma das bibliotecas mais conhecidas é a [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/). Outra é a disponível na [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) do Gnome. O [Apache Portable Runtime](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__hash.html) também tem a sua. Assim como a [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/index.html). Outra conhecida é a [HtHash](https://www.bth.se/people/ska/sim_home/libghthash.html). [Mais uma](http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/khash.h).

Comment: @OP como o bigown já disse, só usando "hashes". Isso se deve porque é realmente o que o JavaScript faz. Os nome das variáveis em C são apenas abreviações para lugares na memória

Comment: @LucasHenrique como em qualquer linguagem, de uma forma ou de outra :)

Comment: realmente, o que muda é o nível de "iterações" =P